# Want to get off a home loan in TN

Tags: home-loan, jointly-held-property

I am in a home loan with my ex-partner in joint tenancy. She is the primary on the loan paperwork.  I would like to remove myself from the loan.  Is that possible?  She does not want to refinance in her name only but rather just remove me from the original which I am fine with.

Comment: Did anyone ask the bank?

Answer (score 7):

This will be up to the bank.  Ask them, but if they are unwilling then refinancing or selling the house are the only other options.  Even changing the title does not release you from the loan obligation.

Answer (score 4):

Both people are responsible for the loan, it doesn't matter who is prime. The lender can ding both parties credit reports for failure to pay. It can force payment from either party.

They are unlikely to want to let one party out of the deal unless they have done an updated review of the solo persons finances and credit.  Of course that type of review is only done as part of a refinance.

Even if you give up your portion of the property via a quit claim deed, that won't get your name off the mortgage.